# Make user input safe for XML

Tags: php, xml, character-encoding

What is the best practice for generating valid XML with PHP from user submitted text, e.g. eCommerce sales data with ampersands, angle brackets, non-ascii accent characters, new lines etc etc.

What functions, libraries, regexes do folks rely on?

Comment: I am currently using CDATA and htmlentities, and after a an accented o in León caused a trainwreck I am removing accented chars with strtr().  Thing is the company back office folks hate the htmlentities() output and their Windows coder can't seem to decode for them.

Comment: Sounds more that you're mixing characterset encodings than having a problem with the CDATA itself. Using htmlentities and CDATA together does not make much sense BTW. So instead of crazy and widely guessing to kill something, first find out where the problem lies. The solution then is often trivial. So what exactly does not work?

Comment: Well what we have is some knuckleheads who used Expression Engine's abstracted storage to make an eCommerce store.  Table encodings are set to match EE.  Store owner's back office is Windows and there is an executable by another party which accepts XML and imports into Great Plains on the Windows box.  I was tasked to write the API which accepts calls from the executable to sync distributors, store products, and distributor and retail orders.  I did not want to wrap every piece of user input in CDATA tags but even when I did I found the accented o issue blowing shtuff up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap information in `CDATA` tags and encode data with [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

```
'<tag><![CDATA[' . htmlentities($theData) . ']]></tag>'
```

Or using [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createcdatasection.php)

```
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8");

/* ... */

$dom->createCDATASection(htmlentities($theData));
```

Comment: Sorry but the answer looks a bit like you have no clue for what CDATA is for and what has htmmlentities to do or not to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want binary safeness, then you need to use an additional transport encoding. For example you can use [base64](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) or [uuencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.convert-uuencode.php) to store the data in a binary safe fashion inside an XML chunk.

Answer (score 0):

- [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)
- [`htmlentities()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Answer (score 0):

You may also try :

[html_entity_decode()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)